# Why CMake custom target won't be built even if dependency was changed

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

My `CMakeLists.txt` files parses some text files where library dependencies are specified by developers. Those files, let's call them `linkfile.txt`, are simple text files listing libraries to be linked with, this makes it easy to developers not familiar with `CMake` to extend a library dependency list.

I use Visual Studio 2015 generator.

Now, when one modifies this text file, Visual Studio does not autoamtically runs CMake to update the solution while you request it to build (it does when you modified an included cmake file or a `CMakeLists.txt` file).

Is there a way to tell `CMake` that some extra files may invalidate the solution and require `CMake` to be ran again?

If not, I already have a custom target to let user manually run CMake when needed:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( RECONFIGURE COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
```

So I could reuse that. But, if I specify `DEPENDS [path_to]/linkfile.txt` parameter to `ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET`, `RECONFIGURE` does not get automatically generated when I request to generate the solution after `linkfile.txt` was modified (while it does if a cmake file or `CMakeLists.txt` file was modified).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell `CMake` that some extra files may invalidate the solution and require `CMake` to be ran again?

Yes. You're looking for the directory property [`CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.html). In your case, you'd use it like this:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS linkfile.txt)
```

However, my experiments with CMake 3.7.2 and VS 2013 show that while the file is actually added to the dependency list in the solution, it is somehow not picked up by the dependency scanner. You can therefore use a workaround by passing the file through `configure_file`:

```
configure_file(linkfile.txt linkfile.txt COPYONLY)
```

This will copy the file from its source location into the binary directory, and *also* introduce it as a dependency of the configuration step in a way which CMake *does* honour.

---

Trying to do this with a custom target would be much more convoluted. CMake's custom targets are *always considered out of date,* so whenever you ask to build a set of targets which includes a custom target, that custom target will be run. Note that custom targets are not part of `all` by default, which is why your target is not getting picked up by a simple solution rebuild. If it was part of `all` (by adding the parameter `ALL` in the `add_custom_target()` call), it would trigger on *every* rebuilds, regardless of dependencies (custom targets are *always* out of date).

The way forward with this would be a custom command to run CMake, which depends on `linkfile.txt` and touches a file `x`. The custom target `RECONFIGURE` would then have `x` in its `DEPENDS`. Building a custom target means all its dependencies must be brought up to date, which would mean the custom command generating `x` "from" `linkfile.txt` would be examined and triggered if necessary.

However, take the above as just explanation; the correct way to solve your issue is by using `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`.

Comment: This looks good. However, when I add `set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "linkfile.txt")`, modify linkfile.txt and then select "Build Solution", CMake is not ran by VS. Also tried with `GLOBAL` rather than `DIRECTORY`, same behaviour. If I modifiy a CMakeLists.txt file, CMake is ran by VS. Note that linkfile.txt is at the same location as the library's CMakeLists.txt...

Comment: @jpo38 Curiouser and curiouser. I see the file listed in the dependencies of `ZERO_CHECK`'s `generate.stamp.rule` in VS, but it's not picking up the dependency. I'll add a workaround to the answer.

Comment: @jpo38 Workaround added and tested. I will play with it some more and submit a CMake bug report if applicable.

Comment: This works, thanks. Note that I had to specify full file path for `configure_file `first parameter (`${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/linkfile.txt`).